# Reading strings from file into dynamically allocated array in C

Tags: c, malloc, fopen

I'm trying to learn C and can't seem to figure out how to read in strings from a file into an array.  I have a 2D array of chars as an array of strings and try to read those in by using malloc but I keep getting a SegFault.  Any tips on how to fix my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_WORDS 10
#define MAX_WORD_SIZE 20

unsigned int getLine(char s[], unsigned int uint, FILE *stream);

int main( void ){

 FILE *infile1;
 unsigned int i = 0;
 unsigned int j = 0;
 unsigned int index;
 char c;

 char wordList[ MAX_WORDS+1 ][ MAX_WORD_SIZE + 1];

 infile1 = fopen("myFile.txt", "r");


 if (!(infile1 == NULL))
printf("fopen1 was successful!\n");


 while( (c = getc(infile1)) != EOF){
  while ((c = getc(infile1)) != ' '){
    wordList[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) );
        wordList[i][j] = getc(infile1);
        j++;
  }
  j = 0;  
  i++;
}


printf("\nThe words:\n");
for (index = 0; index < i; ++index){
printf("%s\n", wordList[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you compiling this.  The compiler should give you and error on the assignment:

```
wordList[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) );
```

The array `wordlist` is not of type `char *`

Also you are missing an include for malloc (stdlib.h probably) and you shouldn't be casting the return from malloc.

Comment: You were right about stdlib.h.  That helped.  And I know the malloc is wrong but I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem - you are allocating one char for wordList[i], then using it as if you had a character for each wordList[i][j].

You don't need to allocate any memory here, as you've defined wordlist as a 2 dimensional array rather than as an array of pointers or similar.

Next obvious problem - you are reading in characters and never providing an end of string, so if you ever got to the printf() at the end you are going to keep going until there happens to be a 0 somewhere in or after wordList[index] - or run off the end of memory, with a Segfault.

Next problem - do you intend to only detect EOF immediately after reading a space - AND throw away alternate characters?

Comment: Got rid of malloc and added in a line to put 0 at the end of words.  Not sure how to fix the last problem you mentioned though.
    while( (c = getc(infile1)) != EOF){'
        while ((c = getc(infile1)) != ' '){
                  if((c = getc(infile1)) = EOF){
                       wordList[i][j+1] = '0';
                       return 0;
      }
           wordList[i][j] = getc(infile1);
           j++;
        }
        wordList[i][j+1] = '0';
        j = 0;  
        i++;
     '}'

Comment: `while( (c = getc(infile1)) != EOF){
     
  while ((c = getc(infile1)) != ' '){


         wordList[i][j] = getc(infile1);
         j++;
      }
      wordList[i][j+1] = '0';
      j = 0;  
      i++;
   }`